# Не передается значение поля input с помощью Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Проблема состоит в том, что отсылается пустая строка, если в ручную в input не прописываю value. 
Есть input и кнопка submit:

```
<input name='text_color' type='text' id ='hex'  class="hex_bodb"  >
<input name='submit_s' id = 'subm' type='submit' value='Информацию о краске' />
```

Результат выводиться в div:

```
<div class="results">Ждем ответа</div>
```

Отбираю тестовое поле и заношу в переменную:

```
var hexx={
            hex: $('input[name=text_color]').val()
        }
```

Ajax:

```
$('#subm').click( function() {

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'response.php?action=sample2',
          data: hexx,
          success: function(data){
            $('.results').html(data);
          }
        });

    });
```

PHP файл, который получает данные:

```
echo 'Цвет  HEX= ' . $_POST['hex'];
```

[image: При том, что ведено значение в поле, все равно отсылается пустота]

Comment: Попробуйте иначе: `var hexx = $('input[name=text_color]').serialize();`

Comment: "Отбираю тестовое поле и заношу в переменную" - когда?

Comment: @ cyadvert не помогло, такой же результат

Comment: @Igor можно подробней, что не так?

Comment: Где находится код: `var hexx={...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас перегружается страница из-за `type="submit"`.

```
$('#subm').click( function() {

    var hexx = {
        hex: $('input[name=text_color]').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'response.php?action=sample2',
        data: hexx,
        success: function(data){
            $('.results').html(data);
        }
    });

    // !!! 
    return false;
});
```

или

```
<input name='submit_s' id='subm' type='button' value='Информацию о краске' />
```